# Working on a form to help me make ebay descriptions

Tags: javascript

I am new to this site and need assistance.

I have some code that a friend (no longer in contact) made for me.  My goal is to add some check boxes to the code so that the selected items will appear in the overall output.
here is my existing code.

```
    <!-- the script to read the options and make the code -->
    <script>
    function makeTemplate(){ var newcode="";
      for (i=0; i<document.source.elements.length; i++){
        newcode=newcode+document.source.elements[i].value;
      }
      document.getElementById('outputview').innerHTML=newcode;
      document.getElementById('outcode').value=newcode;
    }
    </script>
    <!-- end of script -->


    <!-- 
    Notice that quotes inside descriptive elements are not allowed. 
    Use the 7-character code "&amp;rdquo;" instead in the option list values.
    -->


    <form name="source" id="source" >
    <!-- only elements inside this form are added -->

    <select style="width:300px;" >
    <option value=""> NA</option>
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in good condition."           > good condition </option>
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in good working condition."       > good working condition </option>
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in great condition."          > great condition </option>
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in excellent condition."      > excellent condition </option> 
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in excellent working condition."  > excellent working condition </option>
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in new in box NIB condition."     > new in box NIB condition </option>
    <option value="This is corporate surplus in new in bulk bag NIB condition."> new in bulk bag NIB condition </option>
    </select>
    CONDITION <br>
    <br/>

    <input type=text style="width:500px;" value="<br>Unit provides listed voltage as tested by volt meter."><br>
    <br/>

    <select style="width:300px;" >
    <option value=""> NA</option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b> 120vac 60hz. w. 2-prong wall" > 2-prong wall </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b> 120vac 60hz. w. 3-prong wall" > 3-prong wall </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b> 120vac 60hz. w. figure 8 infinity. (NOT included)"  > figure 8 infinity </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b> 120vac 60hz. w. standard computer D. (NOT included)"> standard computer D </option>
    </select>
    INPUT USA <br>
    <br/>



    <select style="width:300px;" >
    <option value=""> NA</option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b>120-240vac 50-60hz. w 2-prong wall "   > 2-prong wall </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b>120-240vac 50-60hz. w 3-prong wall "   > 3-prong wall </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b>120-240vac 50-60hz. w figure 8 infinity. (NOT included) "> figure 8 infinity </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Input: </b>120-240vac 50-60hz. w standard computer D. (NOT included) "> standard computer D </option>
    </select>
    INPUT UNIVERSAL <br>
    <br/>


    <select style="width:300px;" >
    <option value=""> NA</option>
    <option value="<br><b>Output: </b> vac a. ma. tip is AC. 3/16&rdquo; / 5.5mm barrel plug."> 3/16" / 5.5mm barrel plug< /option>
    <option value="<br><b>Output: </b> vac a. ma. tip is AC. Proprietary. " > Proprietary </option>
    </select>
    OUTPUT AC <br>
    <br/>



    <select style="width:300px;" >
    <option value=""> NA</option>
    <option value="<br><b>Output: </b> vdc a. ma. tip is +. 3/16&rdquo; / 5.5mm barrel plug. "> +. 3/16" / 5.5mm barrel plug </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Output: </b> vdc a. ma. tip is -. 3/16&rdquo; / 5.5mm barrel plug. "> -. 3/16" / 5.5mm barrel plug </option>
    <option value="<br><b>Output: </b> vdc a. ma. tip is Proprietary. ">Proprietary</option>
    </select>
    OUTPUT DC <br>
    <br/>


    <textarea style="width:500px; height:200px;">
    <br>
    Please double check your volt, current and connector requirements.        <br>
    On a side note, if you do match all three but 
    the form factor (what it looks like) is different, 
    this may still work for you.<br>
    <b>Manufactured by: </b> <br>
    <b>Web research: </b> <br>
    </textarea>

    <!-- end of included elements -->
    </form>



    <br><input type=submit value="MAKE" onclick="makeTemplate()">


    <!-- preview area -->

    <div id="outputview"><br/><br/>Clicking MAKE will show final output **HERE** based on the code below.<br/></div><br>
    <br/><br/>Output code<br/>
    <textarea style="width:500px; height:200px;" id="outcode"></textarea>
    <br/><br/>
```

So, what i would like to do, is add some check boxes in the code that if checked on the form, they will show up in the outputs at the bottom of the page.  like this...

(checkbox) some text

(checkbox) some other text

(checkbox) a third option

so, if i check the first and third check boxes, "some text" and "a third option" will show up in both outputs at the bottom of the screen, but not the middle one "some other text"

i hope this make sense.